# unable to insert rows from logic table 'Inserted' into another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

If i insert records in table T1, using **output** I want to insert these records from logical table 'inserted' into table T2. Below is my code. If I use the below code records get inserted into T2 but table T1 shows blank...can someone tell me where I am going wrong..

```
create table T1(id int identity(1,1), name vachar(100))

create table T2(id int, name varchar(100))

declare @t table(id int,name varchar(100))

insert into t1(name)
output inserted.id,inserted.name into @t
values('deepak')

insert into t2
select * from @t
```

this is strange ..If I do

```
select * from t1
select * from t2
```

I get value 'deepak' inserted in table T2 and table T1 shows blank.How to insert a record in both the tables T1 and T2 at the same time without using triggers.

Comment: Repro worked for me, you may want to double check the case on your objects, and further quality them.  You reference "T1", "T2" and "t1", "t2", with no schema owner.  Could be the difference.

Comment: Apologies that was a typo t1 and t2 are the same as T1 and T2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to get traction on your problem is to utilize a tool like SQLFiddle. Makes it easy to share and get others looking at your problem quickly :)

[SQLFiddle Output Test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12952/1)

That seems to work for me, although I did see the issue you had with the same exact code you had above. Not sure if it's something related to temp tables, but there's definitely something weird happening.